# User Profiles not syncing Images

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service, user-profile-property

I'm wondering if anyone else has had trouble with their SharePoint 2013 user profile syncs, because I am currently experiencing the problem for several SharePoint users whose profile images do not sync, and therefore do not show up in SharePoint. This isn't happening to all users, or even to a specific group of users. I am at a loss and don't know why this could be happening.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the miisclient for additional sync info? See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2010/07/16/sharepoint-2010-service-applications-userprofile-synch-service-is-not-synching-the-profiles-from-ad.aspx (it's similar for sp2013)

Comment: Images mean Profile Picture, Did you map the Profile picture Property to thumabnail and then run the powershell to create thumbnail and then full sync?

Answer (score 0):

There should be permission issues. Other than that I don't see any issues.

Open this application `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Synchronization Service\UIShell\miisclient.exe` and then run Full Sync.

This application will tell what all got imported and any error etc.

Answer (score 0):

Profile pics do not sync automatically like other properties do. You have to configure this

Make sure you map the 'Picture' field with the 'thumbnailPhoto' AD field then run this Powershell:

```
Update-SPProfilePhotoStore -CreateThumbnailsForImportedPhotos 1 -MySiteHostLocation http://<mySiteURL>/
```

http://richardstk.com/2013/04/12/import-user-photos-from-active-directory-into-sharepoint-2013/